# For what values of $x$ does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please help me to find the values of $x$ in which the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}$$ converges? I applied some tests for it but...:(

Thank you

Comment: @BrettFrankel: I fixed the summation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}=\frac{1}{x+n-1}-\frac{1}{x+n}$$

Answer (score 4):

We can use partial fractions to decompose this fraction. We need to find $A$ and $B$ such that

$$\frac{A}{x+n} + \frac{B}{x+n-1} \equiv \frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)} \, . $$

If we cross multiply, we get $A(x+n-1)+B(x+n)\equiv1$. When $x=-n$ we get $-A\equiv1$ and when $x=1-n$ we get $B \equiv 1$. It now follows that:

$$\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)} \equiv \frac{1}{x+n-1} - \frac{1}{x+n} \, . $$

Let's examine these terms as $n$ advances from $1$. Substituting $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ gives:

$$\left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+3} \right) + \cdots = $$

$$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} + \frac{1}{x+2} - \frac{1}{x+3}  + \cdots $$

You should be able to see that each term is cancelled by the very next term. For this to be well-defined we need the denominators to be non-zero and for the terms to tend to zero. With that in mind, $x$ can be anything but zero or a negative integer. With that in mind we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)} = \frac{1}{x} \, . $$

Answer (score 1):

Besides to @N.S. nice hit.  Think about $S_n$ and find the values that the following limit exists: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=1/x$$

Answer (score 1):

The approach given by N.S. and Babak here is elegant. Here's something a little more direct, which doesn't require you to be clever.

First, figure out which values of $x$ would give you a term with zero in the denominator. Those are obviously bad values for $x$.

Next, note that all but finitely many terms will be positive (in fact all terms will be positive if $x$ is positive), so if the series diverges, the sum must be $+\infty$.

Let's assume $x>1$. If $x<1$, we can let $y$ be $x$ plus some large integer (so that $y>1$) and write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(y+n)(y+n-1)}+\text{finitely many terms}$$

Now $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+n-1)(x+n-1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+n-1)^2}<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$$

That last sum is a convergent $p-$series.

Comment: I think there might be a mistake here. Since $x+n - 1 < x+n$ it follows that $1/(x+n-1) > 1/(x+n)$ and so the first inequality is not valid. As a counter example, let $x=0.5$. The series converges to $2$ but $2 > \pi^2/6$.

Comment: There's an off-by-one error in the last step, but the core argument is correct.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Could you please address the counter example? Putting $x = 0.5$, the argument seems to claim that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4n^2-1} < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} $$ Besides that, the OP asked for the values of $x$ for which the sum converges.
while, in reality:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4}{4n^2-1} = 2 $$
and $2$ is not less than $\pi^2/6 \approx 1.64$. Besides that, the OP asked for the values of $x$ for which the sum converges.

Comment: @FlybyNight It's true that $x+n-1\lt x+n$, but while that means that $\dfrac{1}{(x+n)(x+n+1)}\gt\dfrac{1}{(x+n)^2}$, it also means that $\dfrac{1}{(x+n)(x+n-1)}\lt\dfrac{1}{(x+n-1)^2}$, so by 'bumping' the indices by one the convergence (which is all the OP cares about) still holds.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Please address my counter example. Besides that, the OP asks about the values of $x$ for which the series converges. That question hasn't been addressed.

Comment: @Flybynight Sorry for the error. I've edited the post.

Comment: @BrettFrankel I might be wrong, but isn't there still a mistake. Let us put $x = 1/2$. The inequality says that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+1/2)(x-1/2)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{4n^2-1} = 2 < \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \, . $$

This can't be right because $2$ is not less than $\pi^2/6 \approx 1.64.$ You need $1 < x < \infty$ for final step to hold. But the OP's sum converges to $1/x$ for all $x \notin \{-1,-2,-3,\ldots\}.$ It even hold for complex $x$.

Comment: @FlybyNight When I made the changes, I changed the assumption that $x>0$ to $x>1$ so that all terms are positive. The assumption is without loss of generality since we can pull out the first finitely many terms.